# R : Error in Axis && box : invalid 'y' type in ' x && y'

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the package "scatterplot3d" with R. when I try it like this :

```
data<-read.table("C:\\Users\\Firas\\Desktop\\southafrica.txt",header=TRUE,sep="")
View(data)
colnames(data)
colnames(data) = c("performance","croissance","inflation","balance")

library(scatterplot3d)
scatterplot3d(data$inflation,data$croissance,data$performance,highlight.3d = TRUE, col.axis="blue",col.grid="lightblue",box="False",pch=20,type="h",main="Performance macroeconomique en Afrique du Sud")
```

I get the error : Error in axis && box : invalid 'y' type in 'x && y'
can someone help me please?

Comment: Can you execute `str(data)` and show the results?

Comment: this is what I get when I execute 

`str(data)`

'data.frame': 48 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ performance: num  0.0105 -2.043 -1.3259 -0.3612 -0.5639 ...
 $ croissance : num  3.7 1.5 2 3.5 3.8 3.6 3.9 3.2 3.2 3 ...
 $ inflation  : num  0.5 3.4 3.4 3 3.1 1.4 0.5 -0.7 -1.9 0.4 ...
 $ balance    : num  0.1534 -0.0109 0.3939 0.2384 0.3931 ...

Comment: Have you tried converting the data to a matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code on line 4 to

```
colnames(data) <- c("performance","croissance","inflation","balance")
```

I had the same problem and this way it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue trying to use pipes:

```
# my version would have been like this: 
data<-read.table("C:\\Users\\Firas\\Desktop\\southafrica.txt",
       header=TRUE, 
       sep="") %>%
   colnames(c("performance","croissance","inflation","balance"))

colnames(data)
```

Which produced the same error. I had to change it to this:

```
#solution: 
data<-read.table("C:\\Users\\Firas\\Desktop\\southafrica.txt",
       header=TRUE, 
       sep="") %>%
   `colnames<-`(c("performance","croissance","inflation","balance"))

colnames(data)
```

and it worked just fine.